# How do I find last occurence of "needle" in array php

Tags: php, arrays

There is a built in function for finding array key for a value - [`array_search`](http://www.php.net/array_search). However as you can see from the example, the function only finds first occurrence, whereas I need the last one:

```
<?php
$array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');

$key = array_search('green', $array); // $key = 2;
$key = array_search('red', $array);   // $key = 1;
?>
```

Is there any **built in function** for this?
If not, can I **make a `foreach` go backwards** (from last key to the first one)?

If all the answers are no, I guess this is the only solution:

```
function array_search_last($needle, $array, $strict = false) {
    $keys = array_keys($array);
    //Not sure how smart PHP is, so I'm trying to avoid IF for every iteration
    if($strict) {
      for($i=count($keys)-1; $i>=0; $i--) {
        //strict search
        if($array[$keys[$i]]===$needle)
          return $keys[$i];
      } 
    }
    else {
      for($i=count($keys)-1; $i>=0; $i--) {
        //benevolent search
        if($array[$keys[$i]]==$needle)
          return $keys[$i];
      } 
    }
}
```

I'd prefer something better.

Comment: [array_reverse()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php)

Comment: How fast is that? I could figure that out, but I want the script to be effective.

Comment: why don't you benchmark it and tell us which is more effective

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
array_search('green', array_reverse($array));
```

Reverse it first, then do your search

Comment: I was afraid that reversing the array would take up more resources than using `array_keys`.

Comment: Depends how big your array is i suppose. Since it returns a new array, you would i believe have a copy of the original array so double the data. But if its a smallish array, i wouldn't worry about pre-optimisations. If your application is affected by what is most likely microsecond differences, then your probably using the wrong language.

Comment: I'm parsing quite big XML feed from some site. Big enough to crash browsers when openned. I'm going to use this function to check my current position in XML tree - the script is going to parse the file slowly piece by piece.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean that the script discovers where in the XML it was before it crashed? In which case you should probably approach the problem in a different way. You can run php via command line which negates browser timeout's. So as long as you set the time limit to unlimited, you could in theory run your script for years without it "crashing" due to the parsing time. I would also look at breaking your task into several smaller tasks. I would really be looking at how to code it so it doesn't crash, rather than trying to  work with the crashes

Comment: All the stuff runs on webhosting, paid by my client. In the current program, limit is standard 30 seconds. The script actually does not crash though. It walks through XML (using file functions) and uses standard XML parser on every interesting entry, instead of whole file. When the time's up, it saves offset and other info and exits.
I'm in no hurry while parsing, so I prefer doing it at night in decent intervals.

Comment: array_keys will take more memory (more an assumtion, might be interesting to measure) reason: PHP uss cpy on write with reference counting for variables, this doesn't work for keys, though. With array_keys() it has to create new variables for each element (plus the hashtable holding it), with array_reverse() it can reuse the value objects and simply increase the reference count (unless those are references, then copies are needed ...) und put them in a new hash table

Comment: i think this is not the good solution, as it will it will always return 0, when found; i think a good solution would be, as stated in another answer: array_search('green', array_reverse($array, true));

Answer (score 12):

But all of them missed one thing, that would cause incorrect results for OP's need, he is seeking for index of last element and reversing array will cause to reindex keys (when numeric), so final solution is to set `preserve_keys` param to `TRUE` [see docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php):

```
$array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');

$reversed = array_reverse($array, true);

echo array_search('red', $reversed);
// outs 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more general solution that works for multidimensional associative arrays. It finds all the matching values of a specific column:

```
$needle = array(0 => 'name_2');

$haystack = array(
    23    => array(
        'id' => '23',
        'name' => 'name_1'
    ),
    'arr' => array(
        'id' => 'arr',
        'name' => 'name_2'
    ),
    'arrss' => array(
        'id' => 'arrss',
        'name' => 'name_2'
    )
);

$haystack_name = array_column($haystack, 'name', 'id');
// array(
//      '23' => 'name_1',
//      'arr' => 'name_2'
//      'arrss' => 'name_2'
// )

$name_matches = array_intersect($haystack_name, $needle);
// array(
//      'arr' => 'name_2'
//      'arrss' => 'name_2'
// )

$matches = array_intersect_key($haystack, $name_matches);
// array(
//     'arr' => array(
//         'id' => 'arr',
//         'name' => 'name_2'
//     ),
//     'arrss' => array(
//         'id' => 'arrss',
//         'name' => 'name_2'
//     )
// )

$last_value = $matches[count($matches) - 1];
// array(
//      'id' => 'arrss',
//      'name' => 'name_2'
//     )
```